# can only concatenate str (not "complex") to str

Tags: python, string, typeerror

Why I am getting this error (TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "complex") to str? I am not doing any kind of concatenation in my code. I am confused, please help me.

```
print("%d" % 5+8j)
```

Comment: "I am not doing any kind of concatenation in my code." - what do you suppose the `+` means?

Answer (score 2):

You need parenthesis

```py
print("%s" % (5+8j))
```

Otherwise, it's understood as

```py
print(("%s" % 5)+8j)
```

Incidentally, there is no point in using `%d` instead of `%s`, as it's just less general.

Comment: You can't use %d for complex

Comment: @John Coleman edited accordingly

Answer (score 0):

To convert a complex number to string you have  to do that

```py
print(str(5+8j))
```